# Удаление дублей страниц сайта с index.php на OC

Tags: opencart, редирект

Сайт на Opencart доступен с index.php и (без него).

Задача устранить дубли страниц с index.php.

При настройке редиректа в .htaccess методом:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}" "\/index\.php$"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://cosmetlaser.com/ [R=301,L]
```

и входе в админ панель (вводим лог и пароль) выбрасывает на 404.

Возможно из-за того, что url для входа в админ панель задавался уникальным в целях безопасности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После  `RewriteBase /` ставим:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^\z
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://cosmetlaser.com/? [R=301,L]
```